# Dropdown com JQuery/Ajax só envia dado no primeiro registro

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, dropdown

Estou aplicando um dropdown dinamicamente para cada item de uma lista retornada em PHP. Ao selecionar algum dos itens do dropdown, este valor é enviado a um arquivo Update.php, através de JQuery e Ajax.

O Dropdown:

```
//Aqui tenho um while em PHP para criar um Dropdown para cada registro no Banco de dados
<select id="tipoSel">
   <option value="">Selecione o tipo:</option>
   <option value="Cívil">Cívil</option>
   <option value="Criminal">Criminal</option>
   <option value="Trabalhista">Trabalhista</option>
   <option value="Família">Família</option>
   <option value="Comercial">Comercial</option>
   <option value="Administrativo">Administrativo</option>
 </select>
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $p->current()->id;?>" />
```

O JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(function() {
            $("#tipoSel").bind("change", function(event) {
                var $this = $( this );

                var tipo = $this.val();
                var id = $this.next('input').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "Update.php",
                    data: 'tipo='+tipo+'&id='+id,
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(tipo+' : '+id);
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    });
```

Porém, apesar de ter vários registros, e todos estarem exibindo seu respectivo Dropdown, a função do JQuery só funciona para o primeiro registro da página! Os demais nem exibem o alert...

O que deve estar errado? Como solucionar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

São todos os Dropdowns criados com o `id` de `tipoSel`? O `id` de um elemento deve ser único no DOM enteiro.

usaria uma classe, criando um Dropdown assim:

```
<select class="tipoSel">
   <option value="">Selecione o tipo:</option>
   <option value="Cívil">Cívil</option>
   <option value="Criminal">Criminal</option>
   <option value="Trabalhista">Trabalhista</option>
   <option value="Família">Família</option>
   <option value="Comercial">Comercial</option>
   <option value="Administrativo">Administrativo</option>
 </select>
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $p->current()->id;?>" />
```

E depois no seu jQuery, selecione-as assim:

```
$('.tipoSel').on( ... );
```

Comment: É exatamente isso! Nem havia prestado atenção... Valeu!

Comment: Que bom que deu certo :D